# How to access Angular JS inside string format

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way that I can get angular variable value as below syntax.?

```
var iNumber= "$scope.RegionLineNumber"
```

Comment: Question is unclear

Comment: what exactly do you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) before)

```
var iNumber = eval("$scope.RegionLineNumber");
```

however there's certainly a better way to do that. For example, if you know it's in `$scope`, just use

```
var iNumber = $scope["RegionLineNumber"];
```

Answer (score 1):

why you want to do this. If you want to get in string format then you can use
$scope.RegionLineNumber.toString();

Comment: Its about getting the value dynamically.------- Eg String x="umber"  var iNumber = $scope["RegionLineN"+x];  ----- Hope you get this

Comment: Try this var iNumber = $scope[RegionLineN+x];